# VBA Excel User input lookup data different workbook

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup, worksheet

I am on a very basic level of programming, however, as I am the "skilled" one in my company, I turn to you guys for support, I hope you can help me!

My task at hand is as follows.

I have a working workbook, where all the data entries are done and then I have a database file, also excel.

User file: Random name, as the sheet will change depending on the calculation done by the user. Sheet name "Sagsnr." (Caseno. in local language)

Sourcefile: "Matcost.xls", worksheet: "Matcost"

I need to be able to enter a value e.g. a material number or a range of numbers (So range is dynamic) into the active sheet, which will then start looking up specific field of data related to the ID (Mat. number) in the database file.

I will need to have calculation field in between the various data fetched from the database, so I cannot just copy an entire row, but need to fetch for each ID number a set of values from cells in the database to the user input file.

I would like to only fetch the values and not paste a vlookup function into the sheet as this is both "dangerous from a user manipulation point of view as well as making the sheet slow in my experience.

I have now struggled with the above for quite some time and I have tried to lookup various questions and answers on this site as well, but to no apparent working solution. This might be due to my lack of understanding, but I hope you can then either point me to the right answer or answer it here.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim material As String
Dim fndEntry As Range
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

material = wb1.ActiveCell.Value

' Find the corresponding value in the Database file

Workbooks.Open Filename:="G:\Backoffice\Tilbudsteam\Kostdatabase\Matcost.xls", ReadOnly:=True

Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook

'Change the below Range address..
Set fndEntry = wb2.Range("C:C").Find(What:=material)

'Change the below Range address..
If Not fndEntry Is Nothing Then
    wb2.Range("B" & fndEntry.Row).Copy Destination:=wb1.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
End If


End Sub
```

Thank you very much in advance!

[User input sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZnnw.jpg)

Comment: No attempt at all? What are you working with? Whats the Sheet names, size of data etc? What you said is completely doable, but this site is for fixing and adding to code, not writing it out completely for you.

Comment: Hi, as al my attempts have been to adapt bit and pieces of different codes, I thought it irrelevant and non-value adding, as they probably do their job fine for their minor purpose, but not for my purpose.

But of course I can give you some sheet specifics, sorry for not including them in the beginning:

User file: Random name, as the sheet will change depending on the calculation done by the user. Sheet name "Sagsnr." (Caseno. in local language)

Sourcefile: "Matcost.xls", worksheet: "Matcost"

Comment: I can add some of the codes I have tried, but my conclusion so far is that I am on a very wrong track, therefore I left it out.

Comment: please show to us what you want by giving input data and expected result in atleast screenshot. it will help us to know what you exactly trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably need your method to be on the 'WorkSheet' itself to be able to note when you have entered a 'material number'

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

...

End Sub
```

Inside this you will probably need a `find` method bewteen the ActiveSheet and the Database file

```
Dim material As Variant
Dim fndEntry As Range
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As WorkBook

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

material = wb1.ActiveSheet.ActiveCell.Value

' Find the corresponding value in the Database file

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Somewhere\DataBase.xls

Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
```

Change the below Range address..

```
Set fndEntry = wb2.Sheets("xxx").Range("A:A").Find(What:=material)
```

Change the below Range address..

```
If Not fndEntry Is Nothing Then
    wb2.Sheets("xxx").Range("B" & fndEntry.Row).Copy Destination:= wb1.ActiveSheet.ActiveCell.OffSet(0,1)
End If
```

Pinpointing exactly what you want to do without any code is unfeasible, but the above will do the job, it's just you'll have to change the addresses for certain cells, data..or expand what you need to return to the initial worksheet.

**EDIT**

This should solve your dynamic problem, It checks how many entries you have pasted, typed in, in column C, then returns the data for each of these. You'll need to change the destination column towards the bottom

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim material As Variant
Dim fndEntry As Range
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As WorkBook
Dim lr As Integer

If Not Target.Column = 3 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

lr = wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("C1:C" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If lr < 22 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Workbooks.Open Filename:="G:\Backoffice\Tilbudsteam\Kostdatabase\Matcost.xls", ReadOnly:=True

Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook

For i = 22 To lr

    material = wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("C" & i).Value

    Set fndEntry = wb2.Sheets("Matcost").Range("C:C").Find(What:=material)

    If Not fndEntry Is Nothing Then
        wb2.Sheets("Matcost").Range("E" & fndEntry.Row).Copy Destination:= wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("destination column - change me" & i)
    End If

Next i

wb2.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code proposal, I think you get my idea, but the code gives me an error "438" to the material = wb1.ActiveCell.Value.

Below the entire code, copied and pasted from yours above and only adapted slightly to test the inital feasibility.

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim material As Variant
Dim fndEntry As Range
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

material = wb1.ActiveCell.Value

Workbooks.Open Filename:="G:\Backoffice\Tilbudsteam\Kostdatabase\Matcost.xls", ReadOnly:=True

Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook

'Change the below Range address..
Set fndEntry = wb2.Range("A:A").Find(What:=material)

'Change the below Range address..
If Not fndEntry Is Nothing Then
    wb2.Range("B" & fndEntry.Row).Copy Destination:=wb1.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
End If


End Sub

Comment: Updated in the question field instead above, for reading purposes. :)

Comment: Try changing `Dim material As Variant` to `Integer` or `String` or whatever type you 'material' is

Comment: Thank you, I tried both, but you answered before I could reply. None seems to work? The value I am typing is String, as this could contain both numbers and letters, but the error keeps occuring. The format of the cell is general and I either type in a value or paste a value, none is accepted.

Comment: Perhaps `wb1.ActiveSheet.ActiveCell.Value` is the change needed.

Comment: It still keeps saying 438, somehow it doesnt seem to recognise the possibility of adding the activecell after the activesheet?

Comment: Does `material = wb1.Sheets("sheetName - ChangeMe!").Range("C22").Value` work?

Comment: Yes, it seems to have done the trick, now the 438 error occurs here:

Set fndEntry = wb2.Range("C:C").Find(What:=material)

Comment: I really should explain, my answer was written on a machine that does not have excel installed so it was from memory, therefore please excuse my glaring mistake.  `Set fndEntry = wb2.Sheets("CHANGEME").Range("C:C").Find(What:=material)` this is also on the condition Column `C` is where you keep you `materialid`

Comment: Superb, and considering you are not working in Excel, only makes me more impressed. Thank you for your input and time, it is much appreciated!

It does still fail with a 438 error, but now it is here:

If Not fndEntry Is Nothing Then
    wb2.Sheets("Matcost").Range("E" & fndEntry.Row).Copy Destination:=wb1.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
End If

Comment: You love your 438s!! `Destination:=wb1.ActiveSheet.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)` <-- need to reference the sheet. The `Offset`function is moving across 1 column only, staying on the same row..if this is what's intended

Comment: I really don't, but they seem to love me...

It still fails, it seems to me this resembles the first errors and the activesheet.activecell doesnt work in my excel.

Also getting back to our initial change where we altered the Material to refer only to cell A22, this should be dynamic, could this still be solved?

Comment: I've edited my answer, this should solve the dynamic problem

Comment: Thank you so much, I have now gotten it to fetch some data, however, this was only after altering your code a little. 

"lr" will only stay as value 22, it will not change, even though I put in multiple values below. And the value 22 only occured after i started the lr range from "c23:c"?

Comment: It seems it counts reverse, as I can increase the starting point in "lr" to "C30:C" and then it seems to calculate how many are actually filled in, so I should start from the bottom of the sheet?

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. You can have whatever is needed above Row 22. The `lr` is just finding your last row. So if you have pasted data into `C22`, `C23` & `C24` then `lr = 24`. The For Loop then loops through 22 -> 24 and stops there. There's no way it counts backwards unless you removed
`If lr < 22 Then
    Exit Sub
End If`

Comment: Well, this code seems to work, so I am still very much gratefull! :)

et wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

lr = wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("C20000:C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If lr < 22 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Workbooks.Open Filename:="G:\Backoffice\Tilbudsteam\Kostdatabase\Matcost.xls", ReadOnly:=True

Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook

For i = 22 To lr

    material = wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("C" & i).Value

    Set fndEntry = wb2.Sheets("Matcost").Range("C:C").Find(What:=material)

Comment: One last and final thing, could I just get the values and not the formatting? I think the destination formula copies all, values formats etc., but i would like to preserve the formatting of the user file intact. Possible or do I then need to use a different function?

Comment: `lr = wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("C20000:C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` is terrifying, that really should **not** work. Anyway, to copy just the values, you could write `wb1.Sheets("Sagsnr.").Range("destination column - change me" & i).Value = wb2.Sheets("Matcost").Range("E" & fndEntry.Row).Value`

Comment: Maybe my excel is the reason why I am so unsuccesful, as I agree, the above logic of row calculation shouldn't work, but it does, so I have to abide by it.

Thanks for the other line, I will try this. I cannot thank you enough, you have really helped me!!!

Comment: Well that's why everyone joined SO, it's cos they love it. Have fun!